# Submit function not working on other JavaScript alertbox plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My script is working fine but I want to make the design of my confirm box fancier but I can't make it work because when I use the "document.getElementbyId('btnApprove').submit();" on the plugin's callback method it returns an error " submit() not defined ". How do I use 
"document.getElementbyId('btnApprove').submit();"  to the sweetalert plugin?
Javascript:

```
<script>        
function approval_confirmation(){
    If(confirm("Are you sure")==1){
       document.getElementbyId('btnApprove').submit();
    }
}
<script>
```

Markup:

```
<form method="POST">
<button name="btnApprove" id="btnApprove" onClick="approval_confirmation();return false"> APPROVE</button>
</form>
```

(Transfer the approval_question function to sweetalert2)
Sweetalert 2:

```
  swal({ 
title: 'Are you sure?', 
text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
 type: 'warning', 
showCancelButton: true, 
confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6', cancelButtonColor: '#d33', 
confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!' }).then(function () { 
swal( 'Deleted!', 'Your file has been deleted.', 'success' ) })
```

Comment: [submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) is a function on form elements not buttons

Comment: You need to call `submit()` method on form but not on button.   Or you could use button's `click()` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call submit method on the form, not a button, i.e. in your case it should be like this:

```
<form id="approval-form" method="POST">
<button name="btnApprove" id="btnApprove" onClick="approval_confirmation();return false"> APPROVE</button>
</form>

<script>        
function approval_confirmation(){
    If(confirm("Are you sure") == 1){
       document.querySelector('#approval-form').submit();
    }
}
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either use form id which will search for form attr and submit

```
 document.getElementbyId('formId').submit();
```

or add

```
 <form action="/action_page.php" method="get" id="form1">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
</form>

<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```